# iText digital signature on PDF with more than one image

Tags: java, pdf, itext, jasper-reports, digital-signature

I've a PDF file generated by Jasper Studio.

In this file I've added an image with a specific key. This image serves as placeholder to replace with a digital signature (using iText library).

So, in my PDF file there are more than one image, so I can't discriminate my image, because with `ImageRenderInfo` class I can't get the name on my image, but only its extension (in my case a `PNG` type), but other images have the same image type (PNG).

How can I discriminate my image?

Here, my code, to get my image, in `renderImage` method I try to get info about my image:

```
// To retrieve generated PDF
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = createTemporaryOutputStream();
JasperReportsUtils.render(exporter, populatedReport, baos);
ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());

// Get the reader
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(in);
int pageILikeToCheck = reader.getNumberOfPages();
// Loop all over pages in my PDF to get my image
for (int currPage = 1; currPage <= pageILikeToCheck; currPage++) {
    String matchStr = "DMIMySignatureImg";

    PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);
    parser.processContent(currPagina, new RenderListener() {
    private boolean foundText = false;

    @Override
    public void renderImage(ImageRenderInfo renderInfo) {
        PdfImageObject image;
        try {
            image = renderInfo.getImage();
            if (image == null) return;
            System.out.println("Found image");

            imageCTM = renderInfo.getImageCTM();
            foundText = true;
            System.out.println(renderInfo.getStartPoint());
            if (!foundText) {
                imageCTM = null;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
        }     
    }

    @Override
    public void renderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo) {
        if(renderInfo.getText().length()>0 && matchStr.contains(renderInfo.getText())){
            System.out.println(matchStr);
            System.out.println(renderInfo.getBaseline().getStartPoint());
            System.out.println(renderInfo.getBaseline().getEndPoint());
            foundText = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endTextBlock() {}

    @Override
    public void beginTextBlock() {}
});
```

Comment: *"How can I discriminate my image?"* - What do you *know* about your signature placeholder image to discriminate it by? For example, do you know its size and that size is unique?

Comment: @mkl: Dear, in my pdf can be present more than one image placeholder for signature, so I discriminate (building my repost with Jaspersoft Studio) with key. So I put DMIMySignatureImg1 , 2 and so on. But in this moment, I've put only one image for signature, so the name is DMIMySignatureImg. So the size cannot be unique

Comment: How about using different images for the different signatures?

Comment: @mkl: I've created my file with two images (DMIMySignatureImg1, DMIMySignatureImg2) because when I'll replace with signatures, the user can sign with tablet his signature. So, the user apply twice his signature. But to do this, I prevent add two digital signature object. In my first PDF, for lucky, my image can be replaced (becasue there are no other images), but in my other PDF where there are more than one image for different use, I can't discriminate my image for signature

Comment: To discriminate them you need something that differs between them. And names don't help, neither file names nor image names in Jasper do as they don't go to the PDF. If you don't have anything, you have to change the template.

Comment: @mkl: So, a possible solution is: Image 1 with 150x35 pixel, Image 2 with 151x35 pixel and so on?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203986/discussion-between-joe-taras-and-mkl).